# Retrieved value from field does not show correctly

Tags: javascript, spfx, encoding

I have a question regarding encoding I suppose.

So when a user inputs in a form some value, like this for example:

> (bla {{blabla"bla bla bla" "some more bla bla bla" "bla" "bla bla"}})

and saves it, then this value saved correclty into multiline textfield (rich text).

All good and well.

Now when I retrieve it:

```
await context.spHttpClient.get(context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items(${id})`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json;odata.metadata=none'
      }
    })
```

to display it on the page, then it returns me like this:

> (bla & #123;& #123;blabla & quot;bla bla bla& quot; & quot;some more bla
> bla bla& quot; & quot;bla& quot; & quot;bla bla& quot;& #125;& #125;)

So basically { is encoded in & #123; and " into & quot;
(I had to place *space between & and #123 else it encodes into correct)

And at this point, I'm not sure how to get it all back to normal.

Any idea?
Cuz even here when I type & quot; it turns into "...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `FieldValuesAsText` endpoint to see if that gives you back unencoded (or maybe lesser encoded) values? (Quotes are always going to be difficult because they are essential to how JSON itself is structured.)

So try

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items(${id})/FieldValuesAsText`

and see what that gives you?

Or you could use a trick like the one mentioned [here](https://tertiumnon.medium.com/js-how-to-decode-html-entities-8ea807a140e5) and build yourself a little function to decode it yourself:

```
function decodeHTMLEntities(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.innerHTML = text;
  return textArea.value;
}
```

Comment: it worked with decodeHTMLEntities ...